# Getting an error when creating a calculated column within a query

Tags: sql, oracle

I getting this error message when I execute the code below. What I am trying to get is use the subquery results as my results set for the outer query, my main goal is to create the column defined in the case statement.

Error:

```
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
 1. 00000 -  "FROM keyword not found where expected"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Code:

```
SET DEFINE OFF

SET DEFINE OFF




 CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE EDITIONABLE VIEW "GINSOBADEV_DW"."V_EVAL_QUESTIONNAIRE_F6"("EVAL_PARENT_PI_NUMBER", "AD_RP_CI", "AD_RP_CI2", "AD_JOB_Interest", "AD_JOB_Interest2", "AD_PO", "AD_PO2", "AD_COMPREHENSION_M", "AD_COMPREHENSION_M2", "AD_DETAIL_A", "AD_DETAIL_A2", "AD_NEGOTIATION_P", "AD_NEGOTIATION_P2", "AD_ORGANIZATION_TM", "AD_ORGANIZATION_TM2", "AD_REASONING", "AD_REASONING2", "AD_VERBAL", "AD_VERBAL2", "AD_NON_VERBAL", "AD_NON_VERBAL2", "AD_RP_NonVerbal", "Verb_NonVerb_Index", "Raw_Int_Rp_Score", 
"Int_RP_Quartile","Count_LowRatings1", "Count_LowRatings2", "SERVICE_RP_ACCURACY", "SERVICE_RP_CI","SERVICE_RP_PERSUASIVENESS", "HR_SERVICE_ORIENTATION", "HR_JOB_INTEREST", "HR_PO", "HR_PERSUASION", "SALES_RP_CI", "SALES_RP_CIS", "CSR_RP_DM", "CSR_RP_PERSUASION", "SALES_RP_PERSUASION", "CSR_RP_SO") AS 


SELECT 
a.EVAL_PARENT_PI_NUMBER,
a.AD_RP_CI,
a.AD_RP_CI2, 
a.AD_JOB_Interest, 
a.AD_JOB_Interest2, 
a.AD_PO, 
a.AD_PO2, 
a.AD_COMPREHENSION_M, 
a.AD_COMPREHENSION_M2,
a.AD_DETAIL_A,
a.AD_DETAIL_A2,
a.AD_NEGOTIATION_P
a.AD_NEGOTIATION_P2,
a.AD_ORGANIZATION_TM,
a.AD_ORGANIZATION_TM2, 
a.AD_REASONING, 
a.AD_REASONING2, 
a.AD_VERBAL, 
a.AD_VERBAL2,
a.AD_NON_VERBAL,
a.AD_NON_VERBAL2,
a.AD_RP_NonVerbal,
a.V.erb_NonVerb_Index,
Raw_Int_Rp_Score, 
( CASE        
WHEN a.Raw_Int_Rp_Score <= -.388826 THEN 1
WHEN a.Raw_Int_Rp_Score BETWEEN -.388825999 AND -.004742 THEN 2
WHEN a.Raw_Int_Rp_Score BETWEEN -.063390 AND .706751 THEN 3
WHEN a.Raw_Int_Rp_Score >= .706752  THEN 4
END )  AS Int_RP_Quartile,
a.Count_LowRatings1, 
a.Count_LowRatings2,
a.SERVICE_RP_ACCURACY,
a.SERVICE_RP_CI, 
a.SERVICE_RP_PERSUASIVENESS,
a.HR_SERVICE_ORIENTATION,
a.HR_JOB_INTEREST, 
a.HR_PO, 
a.HR_PERSUASION,
a.SALES_RP_CI,
a.SALES_RP_CIS,
a.CSR_RP_DM,
a.CSR_RP_PERSUASION,
a.SALES_RP_PERSUASION,
a.CSR_RP_SO

  FROM (

  SELECT aa.PARENT_PI_NUMBER EVAL_PARENT_PI_NUMBER,  


                  /*max (
                                CASE
                                WHEN (aa.SBM_EVAL_QUES_CAT_BL = 'Call Center Manager Interview' 
                                AND aa.SBM_EVAL_QUES_DESC_BL = 'Interviewer 1 (Enter your associate ID if you conducted the interview.  Or enter the correct associate ID if someone else conducted the interview):') 
                                THEN
                                                aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_TXT_DT
                                END) As Manager_ID,*/
                /* MAX  (
    CASE
                                WHEN (aa.SBM_EVAL_QUES_CAT_BL = 'Call Center Manager Interview' 
                                AND aa.SBM_EVAL_QUES_DESC_BL = 'Date Evaluation Completed')
                                THEN
                                TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_TXT_DT,'MM-DD-YYYY'),'DD-MON-YYYY')





        END) As MI_Date,*/

        MAX(
      CASE 
        WHEN (aa.SBM_EVAL_QUES_CAT_BL = 'Auto Damage Interview'
        AND  aa.SBM_EVAL_QUES_DESC_BL  = 'Customer Interaction')
        THEN aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL END) AS AD_RP_CI, 


                            MAX (
      CASE
        WHEN (aa.SBM_EVAL_QUES_CAT_BL = 'Auto Damage Interview'
        AND aa.SBM_EVAL_QUES_DESC_BL   = 'Customer Interaction')
        THEN CASE
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '1   (Poor)' THEN 1
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '1+ (Poor Plus)' THEN 2
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '2-  (Weak Minus)' THEN 3
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '2   (Weak)' THEN 4
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '2+ (Weak Plus)' THEN 5
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '3-  (OK Minus)' THEN 6
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL IN( '3 (OK)', '3   (OK)') THEN 7
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '3+ (OK Plus)' THEN 8
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '4-  (Good Minus)' THEN 9
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '4   (Good)' THEN 10
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '4+ (Good Plus)' THEN 11
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '5-  (Excellent Minus)' THEN 12
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '5   (Excellent)' THEN 13
END 
      END) AS AD_RP_CI2,   


       MAX (
      CASE
        WHEN (aa.SBM_EVAL_QUES_CAT_BL = 'Auto Damage Interview'
        AND aa.SBM_EVAL_QUES_DESC_BL   = 'Job Interest')
        THEN aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL
      END)  AS AD_JOB_Interest,


      MAX (
      CASE
        WHEN (aa.SBM_EVAL_QUES_CAT_BL = 'Auto Damage Interview'
        AND aa.SBM_EVAL_QUES_DESC_BL   = 'Job Interest')
        THEN CASE
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '1   (Poor)' THEN 1
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '1+ (Poor Plus)' THEN 2
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '2-  (Weak Minus)' THEN 3
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '2   (Weak)' THEN 4
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '2+ (Weak Plus)' THEN 5
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '3-  (OK Minus)' THEN 6
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL IN( '3 (OK)','3   (OK)') THEN 7
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '3+ (OK Plus)' THEN 8
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '4-  (Good Minus)' THEN 9
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '4   (Good)' THEN 10
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '4+ (Good Plus)' THEN 11
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '5-  (Excellent Minus)' THEN 12
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '5   (Excellent)' THEN 13
END 
      END)  AS  AD_JOB_Interest2,      



    MAX (
      CASE
        WHEN (aa.SBM_EVAL_QUES_CAT_BL = 'Auto Damage Interview'
        AND aa.SBM_EVAL_QUES_DESC_BL   = 'Performance Orientation')
        THEN aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL
      END)  AS AD_PO,   


      MAX (
      CASE
        WHEN (aa.SBM_EVAL_QUES_CAT_BL = 'Auto Damage Interview'
        AND aa.SBM_EVAL_QUES_DESC_BL   = 'Performance Orientation')
        THEN CASE
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '1   (Poor)' THEN 1
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '1+ (Poor Plus)' THEN 2
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '2-  (Weak Minus)' THEN 3
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '2   (Weak)' THEN 4
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '2+ (Weak Plus)' THEN 5
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '3-  (OK Minus)' THEN 6
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL IN( '3 (OK)','3   (OK)') THEN 7
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '3+ (OK Plus)' THEN 8
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '4-  (Good Minus)' THEN 9
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '4   (Good)' THEN 10
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '4+ (Good Plus)' THEN 11
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '5-  (Excellent Minus)' THEN 12
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '5   (Excellent)' THEN 13
END 
      END) AS  AD_PO2, 



        MAX (
      CASE
        WHEN (aa.SBM_EVAL_QUES_CAT_BL = 'AD Assessment'
        AND aa.SBM_EVAL_QUES_DESC_BL   = 'Comprehension & Memory')
        THEN aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL
      END)  AS AD_COMPREHENSION_M,   



     MAX (
      CASE
        WHEN (aa.SBM_EVAL_QUES_CAT_BL = 'AD Assessment'
        AND aa.SBM_EVAL_QUES_DESC_BL   = 'Comprehension & Memory')
        THEN CASE
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '1   (Poor)' THEN 1
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '1+ (Poor Plus)' THEN 2
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '2-  (Weak Minus)' THEN 3
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '2   (Weak)' THEN 4
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '2+ (Weak Plus)' THEN 5
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '3-  (OK Minus)' THEN 6
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '3   (OK)' THEN 7
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '3+ (OK Plus)' THEN 8
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '4-  (Good Minus)' THEN 9
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '4   (Good)' THEN 10
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '4+ (Good Plus)' THEN 11
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '5-  (Excellent Minus)' THEN 12
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '5   (Excellent)' THEN 13
END 
      END) AS  AD_COMPREHENSION_M2, 



      MAX (
      CASE
        WHEN (aa.SBM_EVAL_QUES_CAT_BL = 'AD Assessment'
        AND aa.SBM_EVAL_QUES_DESC_BL   = 'Detail & Accuracy')
        THEN aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL
      END)  AS AD_DETAIL_A,   

      MAX (
      CASE
        WHEN (aa.SBM_EVAL_QUES_CAT_BL = 'AD Assessment'
        AND aa.SBM_EVAL_QUES_DESC_BL   = 'Detail & Accuracy')
        THEN CASE
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '1   (Poor)' THEN 1
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '1+ (Poor Plus)' THEN 2
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '2-  (Weak Minus)' THEN 3
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '2   (Weak)' THEN 4
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '2+ (Weak Plus)' THEN 5
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '3-  (OK Minus)' THEN 6
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '3   (OK)' THEN 7
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '3+ (OK Plus)' THEN 8
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '4-  (Good Minus)' THEN 9
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '4   (Good)' THEN 10
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '4+ (Good Plus)' THEN 11
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '5-  (Excellent Minus)' THEN 12
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '5   (Excellent)' THEN 13
END 
      END)  AS  AD_DETAIL_A2, 






     MAX (
      CASE
        WHEN (aa.SBM_EVAL_QUES_CAT_BL = 'AD Assessment'
        AND aa.SBM_EVAL_QUES_DESC_BL   = 'Negotiation/Persuasion')
        THEN aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL
      END)  AS AD_NEGOTIATION_P,   




       MAX (
      CASE
        WHEN (aa.SBM_EVAL_QUES_CAT_BL = 'AD Assessment'
        AND aa.SBM_EVAL_QUES_DESC_BL   = 'Negotiation/Persuasion')
        THEN CASE
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '1   (Poor)' THEN 1
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '1+ (Poor Plus)' THEN 2
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '2-  (Weak Minus)' THEN 3
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '2   (Weak)' THEN 4
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '2+ (Weak Plus)' THEN 5
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '3-  (OK Minus)' THEN 6
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '3   (OK)' THEN 7
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '3+ (OK Plus)' THEN 8
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '4-  (Good Minus)' THEN 9
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '4   (Good)' THEN 10
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '4+ (Good Plus)' THEN 11
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '5-  (Excellent Minus)' THEN 12
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '5   (Excellent)' THEN 13
END 
      END)  AS  AD_NEGOTIATION_P2,


     MAX (
      CASE
        WHEN (aa.SBM_EVAL_QUES_CAT_BL = 'AD Assessment'
        AND aa.SBM_EVAL_QUES_DESC_BL   = 'Organization & Time Management')
        THEN aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL
      END)  AS AD_ORGANIZATION_TM,  

       MAX (
      CASE
        WHEN (aa.SBM_EVAL_QUES_CAT_BL = 'AD Assessment'
        AND aa.SBM_EVAL_QUES_DESC_BL   = 'Organization & Time Management')
        THEN CASE
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '1   (Poor)' THEN 1
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '1+ (Poor Plus)' THEN 2
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '2-  (Weak Minus)' THEN 3
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '2   (Weak)' THEN 4
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '2+ (Weak Plus)' THEN 5
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '3-  (OK Minus)' THEN 6
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '3   (OK)' THEN 7
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '3+ (OK Plus)' THEN 8
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '4-  (Good Minus)' THEN 9
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '4   (Good)' THEN 10
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '4+ (Good Plus)' THEN 11
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '5-  (Excellent Minus)' THEN 12
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '5   (Excellent)' THEN 13
END 
      END)  AS  AD_ORGANIZATION_TM2, 







      MAX (
      CASE
        WHEN (aa.SBM_EVAL_QUES_CAT_BL = 'AD Assessment'
        AND aa.SBM_EVAL_QUES_DESC_BL   = 'Reasoning')
        THEN aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL
      END)  AS AD_REASONING, 


       MAX (
      CASE
        WHEN (aa.SBM_EVAL_QUES_CAT_BL = 'AD Assessment'
        AND aa.SBM_EVAL_QUES_DESC_BL   = 'Reasoning')
        THEN CASE
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '1   (Poor)' THEN 1
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '1+ (Poor Plus)' THEN 2
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '2-  (Weak Minus)' THEN 3
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '2   (Weak)' THEN 4
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '2+ (Weak Plus)' THEN 5
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '3-  (OK Minus)' THEN 6
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '3   (OK)' THEN 7
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '3+ (OK Plus)' THEN 8
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '4-  (Good Minus)' THEN 9
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '4   (Good)' THEN 10
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '4+ (Good Plus)' THEN 11
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '5-  (Excellent Minus)' THEN 12
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '5   (Excellent)' THEN 13
END 
      END)  AS  AD_REASONING2, 



     MAX (
      CASE
        WHEN (aa.SBM_EVAL_QUES_CAT_BL = 'AD Assessment'
        AND aa.SBM_EVAL_QUES_DESC_BL   = 'Verbal')
        THEN aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL
      END)  AS AD_VERBAL, 

      MAX (
      CASE
        WHEN (aa.SBM_EVAL_QUES_CAT_BL = 'AD Assessment'
        AND aa.SBM_EVAL_QUES_DESC_BL   = 'Verbal')
        THEN CASE
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '1   (Poor)' THEN 1
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '1+ (Poor Plus)' THEN 2
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '2-  (Weak Minus)' THEN 3
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '2   (Weak)' THEN 4
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '2+ (Weak Plus)' THEN 5
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '3-  (OK Minus)' THEN 6
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '3   (OK)' THEN 7
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '3+ (OK Plus)' THEN 8
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '4-  (Good Minus)' THEN 9
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '4   (Good)' THEN 10
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '4+ (Good Plus)' THEN 11
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '5-  (Excellent Minus)' THEN 12
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '5   (Excellent)' THEN 13
END 
      END)  AS  AD_VERBAL2, 



      MAX (
      CASE
        WHEN (aa.SBM_EVAL_QUES_CAT_BL = 'AD Assessment'
        AND aa.SBM_EVAL_QUES_DESC_BL   = 'Non-Verbal')
        THEN aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL
      END)  AS AD_NON_VERBAL, 


      MAX (
      CASE
        WHEN (aa.SBM_EVAL_QUES_CAT_BL = 'AD Assessment'
        AND aa.SBM_EVAL_QUES_DESC_BL   = 'Non-Verbal')
        THEN CASE
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '1   (Poor)' THEN 1
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '1+ (Poor Plus)' THEN 2
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '2-  (Weak Minus)' THEN 3
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '2   (Weak)' THEN 4
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '2+ (Weak Plus)' THEN 5
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '3-  (OK Minus)' THEN 6
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '3   (OK)' THEN 7
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '3+ (OK Plus)' THEN 8
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '4-  (Good Minus)' THEN 9
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '4   (Good)' THEN 10
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '4+ (Good Plus)' THEN 11
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '5-  (Excellent Minus)' THEN 12
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '5   (Excellent)' THEN 13
END 
      END)  AS  AD_NON_VERBAL2,  





        MAX (((
      CASE
        WHEN (aa.SBM_EVAL_QUES_CAT_BL = 'AD Assessment'
        AND aa.SBM_EVAL_QUES_DESC_BL  = 'Non-Verbal')
        THEN CASE
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '1   (Poor)' THEN 1
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '1+ (Poor Plus)' THEN 2
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '2-  (Weak Minus)' THEN 3
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '2   (Weak)' THEN 4
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '2+ (Weak Plus)' THEN 5
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '3-  (OK Minus)' THEN 6
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '3   (OK)' THEN 7
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '3+ (OK Plus)' THEN 8
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '4-  (Good Minus)' THEN 9
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '4   (Good)' THEN 10
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '4+ (Good Plus)' THEN 11
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '5-  (Excellent Minus)' THEN 12
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '5   (Excellent)' THEN 13
END 
      END)- 11.115265)/ 2.636449) AS AD_RP_NonVerbal,



   /* Verbal and Non Verbal Index */


   ( MAX (((
      CASE
        WHEN (aa.SBM_EVAL_QUES_CAT_BL = 'AD Assessment'
        AND aa.SBM_EVAL_QUES_DESC_BL  = 'Verbal')
        THEN CASE
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '1   (Poor)' THEN 1
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '1+ (Poor Plus)' THEN 2
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '2-  (Weak Minus)' THEN 3
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '2   (Weak)' THEN 4
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '2+ (Weak Plus)' THEN 5
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '3-  (OK Minus)' THEN 6
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '3   (OK)' THEN 7
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '3+ (OK Plus)' THEN 8
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '4-  (Good Minus)' THEN 9
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '4   (Good)' THEN 10
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '4+ (Good Plus)' THEN 11
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '5-  (Excellent Minus)' THEN 12
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '5   (Excellent)' THEN 13
END 
      END)- 12.153167)/ 1.416382)    

   +


    MAX (((
      CASE
        WHEN (aa.SBM_EVAL_QUES_CAT_BL = 'AD Assessment'
        AND aa.SBM_EVAL_QUES_DESC_BL  = 'Non-Verbal')
        THEN CASE
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '1   (Poor)' THEN 1
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '1+ (Poor Plus)' THEN 2
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '2-  (Weak Minus)' THEN 3
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '2   (Weak)' THEN 4
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '2+ (Weak Plus)' THEN 5
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '3-  (OK Minus)' THEN 6
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '3   (OK)' THEN 7
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '3+ (OK Plus)' THEN 8
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '4-  (Good Minus)' THEN 9
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '4   (Good)' THEN 10
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '4+ (Good Plus)' THEN 11
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '5-  (Excellent Minus)' THEN 12
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '5   (Excellent)' THEN 13
END 
      END)-11.115265)/2.636449)) AS Verb_NonVerb_Index,



    /* Raw Int-Rp-Score calculation starts here*/






        ( NVL(MAX (((
      CASE
        WHEN (aa.SBM_EVAL_QUES_CAT_BL = 'Auto Damage Interview'
        AND aa.SBM_EVAL_QUES_DESC_BL  = 'Customer Interaction')
        THEN CASE
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '1   (Poor)' THEN 1
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '1+ (Poor Plus)' THEN 2
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '2-  (Weak Minus)' THEN 3
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '2   (Weak)' THEN 4
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '2+ (Weak Plus)' THEN 5
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '3-  (OK Minus)' THEN 6
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL IN( '3 (OK)','3   (OK)') THEN 7
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '3+ (OK Plus)' THEN 8
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '4-  (Good Minus)' THEN 9
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '4   (Good)' THEN 10
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '4+ (Good Plus)' THEN 11
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '5-  (Excellent Minus)' THEN 12
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '5   (Excellent)' THEN 13
END 
      END)-9.312606)/1.884496),0)  

      +

  NVL( MAX (((
      CASE
        WHEN (aa.SBM_EVAL_QUES_CAT_BL = 'Auto Damage Interview'
        AND aa.SBM_EVAL_QUES_DESC_BL  = 'Job Interest')
        THEN CASE
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '1   (Poor)' THEN 1
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '1+ (Poor Plus)' THEN 2
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '2-  (Weak Minus)' THEN 3
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '2   (Weak)' THEN 4
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '2+ (Weak Plus)' THEN 5
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '3-  (OK Minus)' THEN 6
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL IN( '3 (OK)','3   (OK)') THEN 7
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '3+ (OK Plus)' THEN 8
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '4-  (Good Minus)' THEN 9
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '4   (Good)' THEN 10
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '4+ (Good Plus)' THEN 11
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '5-  (Excellent Minus)' THEN 12
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '5   (Excellent)' THEN 13
END 
      END)-9.031373)/1.859445),0)  

      +




      NVL( MAX (((
      CASE
        WHEN (aa.SBM_EVAL_QUES_CAT_BL = 'Auto Damage Interview'
        AND aa.SBM_EVAL_QUES_DESC_BL  = 'Performance Orientation')
        THEN CASE
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '1   (Poor)' THEN 1
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '1+ (Poor Plus)' THEN 2
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '2-  (Weak Minus)' THEN 3
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '2   (Weak)' THEN 4
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '2+ (Weak Plus)' THEN 5
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '3-  (OK Minus)' THEN 6
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL IN( '3 (OK)','3   (OK)') THEN 7
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '3+ (OK Plus)' THEN 8
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '4-  (Good Minus)' THEN 9
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '4   (Good)' THEN 10
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '4+ (Good Plus)' THEN 11
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '5-  (Excellent Minus)' THEN 12
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '5   (Excellent)' THEN 13
END 
      END)-8.831373)/1.936816),0) 

      +





     NVL( MAX (((
      CASE
        WHEN (aa.SBM_EVAL_QUES_CAT_BL = 'AD Assessment'
        AND aa.SBM_EVAL_QUES_DESC_BL  = 'Comprehension & Memory')
        THEN CASE
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '1  (Poor)' THEN 1
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '1+ (Poor Plus)' THEN 2
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '2-  (Weak Minus)' THEN 3
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '2   (Weak)' THEN 4
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '2+ (Weak Plus)' THEN 5
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '3-  (OK Minus)' THEN 6
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '3   (OK)' THEN 7
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '3+ (OK Plus)' THEN 8
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '4-  (Good Minus)' THEN 9
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '4   (Good)' THEN 10
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '4+ (Good Plus)' THEN 11
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '5-  (Excellent Minus)' THEN 12
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '5   (Excellent)' THEN 13
END 
      END )-7.280893)/2.652814),0)   

      +



     NVL(MAX (((
      CASE
        WHEN (aa.SBM_EVAL_QUES_CAT_BL = 'AD Assessment'
        AND aa.SBM_EVAL_QUES_DESC_BL  = 'Detail & Accuracy')
        THEN CASE
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '1   (Poor)' THEN 1
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '1+ (Poor Plus)' THEN 2
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '2-  (Weak Minus)' THEN 3
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '2   (Weak)' THEN 4
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '2+ (Weak Plus)' THEN 5
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '3-  (OK Minus)' THEN 6
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '3   (OK)' THEN 7
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '3+ (OK Plus)' THEN 8
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '4-  (Good Minus)' THEN 9
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '4   (Good)' THEN 10
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '4+ (Good Plus)' THEN 11
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '5-  (Excellent Minus)' THEN 12
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '5   (Excellent)' THEN 13
END 
      END)-7.018172)/2.602932),0) 

      +




      NVL( MAX (((
      CASE
        WHEN (aa.SBM_EVAL_QUES_CAT_BL = 'AD Assessment'
        AND aa.SBM_EVAL_QUES_DESC_BL = 'Negotiation/Persuasion')
        THEN CASE
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '1   (Poor)' THEN 1
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '1+ (Poor Plus)' THEN 2
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '2-  (Weak Minus)' THEN 3
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '2   (Weak)' THEN 4
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '2+ (Weak Plus)' THEN 5
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '3-  (OK Minus)' THEN 6
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '3   (OK)' THEN 7
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '3+ (OK Plus)' THEN 8
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '4-  (Good Minus)' THEN 9
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '4   (Good)' THEN 10
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '4+ (Good Plus)' THEN 11
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '5-  (Excellent Minus)' THEN 12
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '5   (Excellent)' THEN 13
END 
      END)-7.894600)/2.393238),0) 

     +



             NVL( MAX (((
      CASE
        WHEN (aa.SBM_EVAL_QUES_CAT_BL = 'AD Assessment'
        AND aa.SBM_EVAL_QUES_DESC_BL  = 'Organization & Time Management')
        THEN CASE
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '1   (Poor)' THEN 1
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '1+ (Poor Plus)' THEN 2
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '2-  (Weak Minus)' THEN 3
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '2   (Weak)' THEN 4
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '2+ (Weak Plus)' THEN 5
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '3-  (OK Minus)' THEN 6
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '3   (OK)' THEN 7
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '3+ (OK Plus)' THEN 8
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '4-  (Good Minus)' THEN 9
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '4   (Good)' THEN 10
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '4+ (Good Plus)' THEN 11
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '5-  (Excellent Minus)' THEN 12
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '5   (Excellent)' THEN 13
END 
      END) -7.630322)/1.839931),0) 

      +



        NVL(MAX (((
      CASE
        WHEN (aa.SBM_EVAL_QUES_CAT_BL = 'AD Assessment'
        AND aa.SBM_EVAL_QUES_DESC_BL  = 'Reasoning')
        THEN CASE
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '1   (Poor)' THEN 1
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '1+ (Poor Plus)' THEN 2
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '2-  (Weak Minus)' THEN 3
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '2   (Weak)' THEN 4
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '2+ (Weak Plus)' THEN 5
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '3-  (OK Minus)' THEN 6
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '3   (OK)' THEN 7
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '3+ (OK Plus)' THEN 8
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '4-  (Good Minus)' THEN 9
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '4   (Good)' THEN 10
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '4+ (Good Plus)' THEN 11
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '5-  (Excellent Minus)' THEN 12
when aa.SBM_EVAL_ANS_DESC_BL = '5   (Excellent)' THEN 13
END 
      END)-7.993250)/2.411327),0))/8 as Raw_Int_Rp_Score,


                (    
SELECT B.* FROM AAA_V_EVAL_QUESTIONNAIRE_BASE B



) aa )a
group by PARENT_PI_NUMBER;
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: If you run the query on its own you'll see which line reports the error. You're missing a comma after `a.AD_NEGOTIATION_P` (line 14 of the query part) for a start, but then the query doesn't seem to finish properly either. The `) a` on the penultimate line doesn't seem to be related to anything. You need to run the query on its own, breaking it down if necessary to manageable chunks, to figure out what it's supposed to do and where it's going wrong. Formatting it might help too...

Comment: This sort of thing is a syntax error. Because your query is so  long tracking it down is hard work. But it's harder work for us that it has for you, because you have the base tables so you can run the query - or bits of it - and get feedback from the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WAAAAAY down in your awesome long and tedious query there is the following code:

```
..END)-7.993250)/2.411327),0))/8 as Raw_Int_Rp_Score,


                (    
SELECT B.* FROM AAA_V_EVAL_QUESTIONNAIRE_BASE B



) aa )a
group by PARENT_PI_NUMBER;
```

First of all, your selected columns finish with a comma, which should not be. You should not have comma here:

```
as Raw_Int_Rp_Score,
```

Then, you are missing the from clause.

My best guess is that you should change it to this:

```
..END)-7.993250)/2.411327),0))/8 as Raw_Int_Rp_Score


                   FROM (    
    SELECT B.* FROM AAA_V_EVAL_QUESTIONNAIRE_BASE B



    ) aa )a
```

Comment: Nop.e. He selects things from aa in the calculation, so that means his columns end at Raw_Int_Rp_Score and select from aa.

Comment: where should the from clause be exactly?

Comment: i had cut the if it helps i can add the rest of the code here

Comment: @JKim dude I sincerely hope this table is small dude, cuz your query will run forever... Don't you have any way to optimize?! Maybe use several tables or smth...

Comment: @AlexPoole Well, I guess I write worse code than you and I'm used to it lol :)

Comment: Here is the most puzzling thing, i cleared the error message but then the calculated column which is defined by the case statement is not getting created,and i only get a subset of the columns instead of all the columns i am expecting

Comment: @JKim I bet you are not selecting it at the final query, here: SELECT 
a.EVAL_PARENT_PI_NUMBER,
a.AD_RP_CI,
a.AD_RP_CI2, 
a.AD_JOB_Interest, 
a.AD_JOB_Interest2, 
a.AD_PO, ... Please mark my answer as valid after we are done.

Comment: No, the caculated column did not exist, the whole point of this subquery is to create that calculated column

Comment: Guys i am still in the dog house on this one , anyone else that wants to take a stab at it will be highly appreciated.

Comment: @JKim Intellisense may not be working, Calculated column exists in a SUBQUERY and you should call it from there in the FIRST SELECT CLAUSE. I'm not ragetyping, just marking important concepts.

Comment: Here is what i am doing. I have the calculated column on the create statement as well as on the first select statement. isnt that right or way its supposed to work?

Comment: @JKim Yes, I guess. I am checking atm. Just tell me what is the result of the query? What do you mean by not getting created? Doest it return null or compilation error?

Comment: when i run execute the query i only get all the columns in the outer querry except for this one ( Int_RP_Quartile) the results that i expect on this column are created on a different column all together ( Raw_Int_Rp_Score)

Comment: So maybe you have a problem with the ordering. Please check explicitly which column you put where in the brackets after the View name. Just Create whole new view like this:

Create FORCE Editionable View "GINSOBADEV_DW"."V_EVAL_QUESTIONNAIRE_F6_v2" AS Select.... and maybe it will solve the problem.

Comment: i have confirmed that the ordering is  right but still not getting all the columns

Comment: Now saying FROM keyword not found where expected

Comment: @JKim - you need to take responsibility for your own code. You have written an unreasonably long query without apparently incrementally testing as you went along. Consequently you have **multiple syntax errors**. You need to do what you should have done at the outset. Write a small part of the final query. Get that working. Extend it. get that working. Iterate until you have implemented all your logic.

Comment: I had built this querry incrementally and tested all the way to the point where i am adding a new column based on the case statement at the top.