# SQL command when creating a view

Tags: oracle

I am trying to create a view in oracle 11g  on the following code
    but getting an error saying command not ended properly, anyone in a
    position to point me in the right direction or correct me.

```
CREATE 
OR 
replace FORCE editionable VIEW "GINSOBADEV_DW"."V_PSI" ( "PARENT_PI_NUMBER","REQUEST_NUM","PI_CANDIDATE_NUM","PSI_SCORE","PSI_Xmation","PSI_BAND" ) AS
SELECT request_num, 
       pi_candidate_num, 
       psi_score, 
       psi_xmation, ( 
       CASE 
              WHEN dd.psi_xmation <=      -0.880927 THEN 1 
              WHEN dd.psi_xmation BETWEEN -0.880926 AND    -0.063391 THEN 2 
              WHEN dd.psi_xmation BETWEEN -0.063390 AND    0.706751 THEN 3 
              WHEN dd.psi_xmation >= 0.706752 THEN 4 
       END ) AS psi_band 
FROM   ( 
              SELECT request_num, 
                     pi_candidate_num, 
                     request_last_modified_dt, 
                     coalesce (gco_ad_knowledge_test_score,psi_overall_score)                       AS psi_score,
                     (coalesce(gco_ad_knowledge_test_score, psi_overall_score) -39.035024)/8.439997 AS psi_xmation
              FROM  ( 
                            SELECT arank, 
                                   parent_pi_number, 
                                   request_num, 
                                   pi_candidate_num, 
                                   psi_overall_score, 
                                   gco_ad_knowledge_test_score, 
                                   request_last_modified_dt 
                            FROM  ( 
                                            SELECT   row_number() over (PARTITION BY pi_candidate_num ORDER BY request_last_modified_dt DESC,request_num ) arank ,
                                                     parent_pi_number, 
                                                     request_num, 
                                                     pi_candidate_num, 
                                                     psi_overall_score, 
                                                     gco_ad_knowledge_test_score, 
                                                     request_last_modified_dt 
                                            FROM     wc_application_event_f 
                                                     --   where rownum =1 
                                            WHERE    ( 
                                                              psi_overall_score IS NOT NULL 
                                                     OR       gco_ad_knowledge_test_score IS NOT NULL)
                                                     -- GCO_AD_KNOWLEDGE_TEST_SCORE != '10100' and    --AND PI_CANDIDATE_NUM IN (4119830,4781686      ) 
                                   ) cc 
                            WHERE  arank =1 ) bb )dd;
```

Comment: I can't believe you're still posting horribly formatted complicated views and expecting us to debug them for you.

Comment: This is an absolute mess, and you're going to need to straighten it out yourself.

Comment: this is the portion causing the error. the rest of the block of code is running fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I simplified the query that you submitted. Because honestly, like K Sly and Zak and APC indicated, your formatting is terrrrrrible.

That brought me here:

```
CREATE OR replace FORCE editionable VIEW "GINSOBADEV_DW"."V_PSI" ( "PARENT_PI_NUMBER","REQUEST_NUM","PI_CANDIDATE_NUM","PSI_SCORE","PSI_Xmation","PSI_BAND" ) AS
SELECT dd.request_num, 
       dd.pi_candidate_num, 
       dd.psi_score, 
       dd.psi_xmation, 
       (CASE 
              WHEN dd.psi_xmation <=      -0.880927 THEN 1 
              WHEN dd.psi_xmation BETWEEN -0.880926 AND    -0.063391 THEN 2 
              WHEN dd.psi_xmation BETWEEN -0.063390 AND    0.706751 THEN 3 
              WHEN dd.psi_xmation >= 0.706752 THEN 4 
       END) AS psi_band 
  FROM (SELECT bb.request_num, 
               bb.pi_candidate_num, 
               bb.request_last_modified_dt, 
               coalesce (bb.gco_ad_knowledge_test_score, bb.psi_overall_score)                        AS psi_score,
               ((coalesce(bb.gco_ad_knowledge_test_score, bb.psi_overall_score) -39.035024)/8.439997) AS psi_xmation
          FROM (SELECT cc.arank, 
                          cc.parent_pi_number, 
                          cc.request_num, 
                          cc.pi_candidate_num, 
                          cc.psi_overall_score, 
                          cc.gco_ad_knowledge_test_score, 
                          cc.request_last_modified_dt 
                     FROM (SELECT row_number() over (PARTITION BY pi_candidate_num ORDER BY request_last_modified_dt DESC, request_num ASC) arank ,
                                  parent_pi_number, 
                                  request_num, 
                                  pi_candidate_num, 
                                  psi_overall_score, 
                                  gco_ad_knowledge_test_score, 
                                  request_last_modified_dt 
                             FROM wc_application_event_f 
                            WHERE (psi_overall_score IS NOT NULL OR gco_ad_knowledge_test_score IS NOT NULL)) cc 
                    WHERE cc.arank =1)bb)dd;
```

I feel that this query is still way too complex for whatever it is you're trying to achieve. Not to mention, you have parameters coming in that aren't being used anywhere.

So I simplified it down this this query:

```
CREATE OR replace FORCE  VIEW "V_PSI" AS
with calculated_values as
         (select request_num,
                 pi_candidate_num, 
                 coalesce (gco_ad_knowledge_test_score, psi_overall_score) AS psi_score,
                 ((coalesce(gco_ad_knowledge_test_score, psi_overall_score) -39.035024)/8.439997) AS psi_xmation,
                 row_number() over (PARTITION BY pi_candidate_num ORDER BY request_last_modified_dt DESC, request_num ASC) arank
            from wc_application_event_f
           where psi_overall_score IS NOT NULL OR gco_ad_knowledge_test_score IS NOT NULL)
SELECT request_num, 
       pi_candidate_num, 
       psi_score, 
       psi_xmation, 
       (CASE 
              WHEN psi_xmation <=      -0.880927 THEN 1 
              WHEN psi_xmation BETWEEN -0.880926 AND    -0.063391 THEN 2 
              WHEN psi_xmation BETWEEN -0.063390 AND    0.706751 THEN 3 
              WHEN psi_xmation >= 0.706752 THEN 4 
       END) AS psi_band 
  FROM calculated_values
  where arank = 1;
```

And then I ran into all kinds of trouble when I added the editionable clause back in (which, btw, is actually "editioning")

First, Oracle didn't like the "with" statement; it generated an ORA-00922, so I moved it into a subquery again.

Then it complained with an ORA-00936 which is a missing statement.

Long story short, I went through several iterations and COULD NOT perform the query as part of a view. I think you need to provide more background as to WHY you're using an editionable view here. Also, why force the results to be limited to the first one?

Resources for you to look into:

1. https://www.morganslibrary.org/reference/editioning_views.html
   Morgan's library is amazing for almost anything SQL and PL/SQL
2. http://sqlfiddle.com/
   SQL Fiddle lets you specify your database, build your schema, and test your statements. All for free.
3. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e41502/adfns_editions.htm#ADFNS020
   This is Oracle's reference sheet for Editionable Views. Use it responsibly.
4. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2010/10-mar/o20asktom-098897.html
   Ask Tom goes into Editioning in depth. There's a lot to read, but he has some solid examples.

Comment: Thanks very much. I formatted your  code and it worked. I will try to be  more careful with my  code format next time

Answer (score -1):

I guess it depends on how you're implementing this. If you run it in SQL*Plus, it would read the double-new line characters as a new statement.

Try removing the new line characters so that there's no more than one line-break per line. Removing the comments will also help. EG:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE EDITIONABLE VIEW "GINSOBADEV_DW"."V_PSI" (
"PARENT_PI_NUMBER","REQUEST_NUM","PI_CANDIDATE_NUM","PSI_SCORE","PSI_Xmation","PSI_BAND"
)  AS  SELECT  REQUEST_NUM,PI_CANDIDATE_NUM,PSI_SCORE,PSI_Xmation,
(CASE  WHEN DD.PSI_Xmation <= -0.880927 THEN 1 WHEN DD.PSI_Xmation
BETWEEN -0.880926 AND -0.063391 THEN 2 WHEN DD.PSI_Xmation BETWEEN
-0.063390 AND  0.706751 THEN 3 WHEN DD.PSI_Xmation >= 0.706752 THEN 4  END ) AS PSI_BAND
FROM  ( SELECT
REQUEST_NUM,PI_CANDIDATE_NUM,REQUEST_LAST_MODIFIED_DT, COALESCE
(GCO_AD_KNOWLEDGE_TEST_SCORE,PSI_OVERALL_SCORE) AS PSI_SCORE,
(COALESCE(GCO_AD_KNOWLEDGE_TEST_SCORE, PSI_OVERALL_SCORE)
-39.035024)/8.439997 AS PSI_Xmation
FROM(
SELECT
ARANk,PARENT_PI_NUMBER,REQUEST_NUM,PI_CANDIDATE_NUM,PSI_OVERALL_SCORE,GCO_AD_KNOWLEDGE_TEST_SCORE,REQUEST_LAST_MODIFIED_DT
FrOM( SELECT     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION  BY PI_CANDIDATE_NUM
ORDER BY REQUEST_LAST_MODIFIED_DT DESC,REQUEST_NUM  ) ARANK  
,PARENT_PI_NUMBER,REQUEST_NUM,PI_CANDIDATE_NUM,PSI_OVERALL_SCORE,GCO_AD_KNOWLEDGE_TEST_SCORE,REQUEST_LAST_MODIFIED_DT
FROM    WC_APPLICATION_EVENT_F
WHERE (PSI_OVERALL_SCORE IS NOT NULL OR GCO_AD_KNOWLEDGE_TEST_SCORE
IS NOT Null)
     ) CC   WHERE  ARANK =1 ) BB )DD;
```

Comment: I am using SQL Developer. i Tried to run it with the new changes but still getting an error

Comment: Is there a way to find out what is causing the error when i create view, it says its been created with a warning message like this (Failed: Warning: execution completed with warning)

Comment: You could start by removing all the complicated bits from the query and add them one-at-a-time, re-running the statement in-between.

I suspect it might have to do with the "select row_number() over (partition by ..." bits, but I'm not sure, I've never encountered that before.

Comment: *"You could start by removing all the complicated bits from the query and add them one-at-a-time"* - very sound advice. If only somebody had already suggested that approach some time ago. [Oh hang on a minute ...](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49069625/146325)

Comment: All you're really doing here is trying to teach him how to troubleshoot his own issue .. This answer doesn't answer *what* the OP issue **is** ..  IMHO  he needs to learn his own troubleshooting skills, and helping someone to troubleshoot unreasonable code doesn't help the community, which is the point of Stack Overflow.

Comment: @APC: I read this question in isolation. Am I supposed to go check all of StackOverflow for similar or previous questions by the user, or take what looks like an issue and deal with it as it is? You can see I don't have many reputation points yet, I'm still new here.

Comment: @Zak: If I don't know the exact answer, but I know how to help him FIND the correct answer, shouldn't I do that? Couldn't my suggestions help someone else in the future? You'd be amazed at the number of people who don't think to simplify first.

Comment: @SerenaC - my comment was not really aimed at you, but at the OP who has asked several questions regarding this piece of code, and had been given advice by several people on how to frame a decent question and had ignored them all. So, no you're not expected to *"check all of StackOverflow"*. But when confronted with an obviously poor question you are expected to ask whether answering it is appropriate, or whether to something else instead. To be fair, with the rep you have right now there's not much else you can do except pass and find another question to answer.